# Automate mysql table entry

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert mysql data table values from a excel file , in php.I googled a lot for it and none of them worked .
The excel table is like this:
[The excel file which i want to upload it to mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef36g.jpg)

Comment: what you tried so far .show the code

Comment: You need to make import function from  excel data from excel to mysql database..??

Comment: @DharmendraSingh : No no, just use any libraries or other functions for my project.

Comment: is that a .csv file?

Comment: you need PHPExcel Library to import your excel to database..  http://www.ilovephp.net/php/how-to-import-excel-file-data-into-mysql-database-in-php/

Comment: @DharmendraSingh  : Got the phpexcel library ,it worked ..thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest save the file in csv format and upload using "Load data infile"

check the mysql documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

```
CREATE TABLE sample 
(
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
   rollno INT, 
   admnno INT, 
   name varchar(50),
   dob Date,
   classid INT, 
   guardian varchar(50),
   contactno INT
);


LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/sample.csv' 
INTO TABLE sample  
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
   OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES  TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: I want to do it through php code.

Comment: Okay. Can you change the file to csv format or want to use Excel only? You can use [PHPExcelReader](https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/) if you want you use excel only otherwise use fgetcsv() for csv format

Comment: OKAY,got your point ,i simply used the phpexcelReader..problem solved